# C: If the parameters are pushed from right to left, why do the following happen? (64-bit operation system, 32-bit program)

Tags: c, stack

By the calling convention used in x86 architecture, arguments are passed via the stack on function call. The order of pushing the arguments is said to be from *right to left*. The following example conforms to it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test(int a, int b, int c) {
    printf("%p\n%p\n%p\n", &a, &b, &c);
}
int main(void) { 
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    int c = 3;
    test(a, b, c);
    return 0;
}
```

the result is：

```
0xffbc4bf0
0xffbc4bf4
0xffbc4bf8
```

I can understand that，but here, the arguments seem to be neither in descending not in ascending order:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test(int a, char b, int c) {
    printf("%p\n%p\n%p\n", &a, &b, &c);
}
int main(void) { 
    int a = 1;
    char b = 2;
    int c = 3;
    test(a, b, c);
    return 0;
}
```

the result is：

```
0xffd6fda0
0xffd6fd88
0xffd6fdac
```

The address of `b` is not in between that of `a` and `c`. Why does this happen?

**UPDATE**

compiler： gcc 4.8.4

OS：Ubuntu 14.04 x86-64

compile command： `gcc -m32 -o test test.c`

Comment: When you write your code, do you use Paint or another graphics program? If you're like the rest of us, the answer to that is *No, I use a text editor*, which means there is absolutely no reason to be posting an image of your code. There is also no reason to post an image of text in a console or terminal window, which can also be copied and pasted here directly as text. Please see [ask] and [mcve], and then come back and [edit] your post. Thanks.

Comment: @KenWhite Thinking about writing code in paint made me laugh so hard. :)

Comment: @RetiredNinja: You won't laugh so hard if you really try doing it. And compilers really hate it, too. :-)

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: @Kingsley gcc 4.8.4

Comment: @huyanbing Please make the question complete by updating the TODO part regarding your machine, compiler, OS and the compiler flags.

Comment: If you look at [the compiler output](https://godbolt.org/z/Ts_zoL) you can see that the compiler is passing the address of the arguments `a` and `c` to `printf`, but it is passing the address of a local copy of argument `b`.  This is presumably because it is expecting that there might be garbage in the upper 24 bits of the argument stack slot that contains `char b`.

Comment: Here is the GCC assembly output that might shed some light: movl $1, -16(%ebp); movb $2, -17(%ebp); movl $3, -12(%ebp)

Answer (score 1):

The base of your problem is the passing of parameters to a program.  Consider your function, which prints the *address of* each parameter.

```
void test(int a, int b, int c)
{
    print("a=%p, b=%p, c=%p\n", &a, &b, &c);
}
```

When parameters are passed to a function, they are pushed onto the stack *in order*.
So when the function `test()` executes, the values of `a`, `b` and `c` are used from the stack (and removed on return).

These are becoming out of order because the compiler is optimising your code.  It's packing the smaller `char` first - possibly in case there's a few more chars that can be packed into the same `word`.  A lot of architectures have speed penalties for accessing items on non-word aligned boundaries.  Word size being dependent on the architecture.  So it's not unreasonable for the compiler to re-arrange your parameters for better performance.  Here it seems  the compiler is shrinking items for better size performance (or suchlike).

Consider these two sets of results, GCC 7.3.0

Without optimisation:

```
$ ./stack_a.exe
0xffffcbf0
0xffffcbf8
0xffffcc00

$ ./stack_b.exe
0xffffcbf0
0xffffcbf8   <-- in order, used 8 bytes
0xffffcc00
```

And with optimisation (-O7):

```
$ ./stack_a.exe
0xffffcc14
0xffffcc18
0xffffcc1c

$ ./stack_b.exe
0xffffcc18  
0xffffcc17  <-- out of order, used 1 byte
0xffffcc1c
```

Interesting that it's reserving 8 bytes per item on the non-optimised run (normal for 64bit) but changing these to 4 bytes when optimised.

Comment: Isn't that exactly the point of his question? If the addresses come from the stack, why the output of the second program is neither ascending nor descending?

Comment: thanks,I  edited my post  again,when b is char ,the address is not continuously

Comment: @NandakumarEdamana  The error lies in believing that taking the address of a function argument gives you the same address that the compiler used to pass that argument into the function. There's no such guarantee at all, the compiler could copy that argument to some other place on the stack because that makes debugging easier, or if optimization is turned on , it could reorder and merge values on the stack that provides for better optimization.

Comment: @nos What you say is correct, except the first sentence. Confusion arises even one knows the addresses come from the argument stack. Optimization is the answer for it, but Kingsley's first answer didn't explain it, and that's why I wrote so.